# Intro to Java: How to use an if statment when a string doesn't exist

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm trying to get the code to output when someone only inputs two of their names, but I can't figure it out. I've tried using  `if (nameFML==null) and (nameFML[2].isEmpty())` but I still get a "exception in thread main java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception: 2" error whenever I type in a name like John Doe.  Other than that the program does what it's supposed to.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Assignment3
    {
      public static void main(String[] args)
      {

       //Declaring variables
        String inputName;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

       //Asking user for keyboard input.
        System.out.println("What are your first, middle, and last names? ");
        inputName = in.nextLine();

       //Users First Input restated
        System.out.println(inputName);

       //Splitting the string "inputName" up by making spaces(" ") delimiters.
       if (inputName.contains(" "))
        {
          String[] nameFML = inputName.split(" ");

       // Creates new strings from the new "nameFML" variable, which was created from "inputName" being split.
          String firstInitial = nameFML[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
          String middleInitial = nameFML[1].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
          String lastInitial = nameFML[2].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();

       //The if method determines whether or not the user inputed in three tokens, two, or an incorrect amount.
          if (nameFML.length== 2)
          {
            System.out.println("Your initials are: " + firstInitial + middleInitial);

        //Separated the print the Variation One print command because it's the only way I could get ".toUpperCase" to work properly.
            System.out.print("Variation One: " + (nameFML[1].toUpperCase()));
            System.out.println(", " + nameFML[0]);

            System.out.println("Variation Two: " + nameFML[1] + ", " + nameFML[0]);


          }
          else
          {
            System.out.println("Your initials are: " + firstInitial + middleInitial + lastInitial);

        //Separated the print the Variation One print command because it's the only way I could get ".toUpperCase" to work properly.
            System.out.print("Variation One: " + (nameFML[2].toUpperCase()));
            System.out.println( ", " + nameFML[0] + " " + lastInitial + ".");

            System.out.println("Variation Two: " + nameFML[2] + ", " + nameFML[0] + " " + nameFML[1]);
          }
        }
        else
        {
      System.out.println("Wrong. Please enter your name properly.");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if (nameFML!=null && !nameFML[2].isEmpty())`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that if the string only has two parts, the third element of the array (index `2`) isn't empty - it just doesn't exist. Therefore, the code fails at

```
String lastInitial = nameFML[2].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
```

If you move these lines

```
String firstInitial = nameFML[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
String middleInitial = nameFML[1].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
String lastInitial = nameFML[2].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
```

into the appropriate if statements, everything should work fine. `nameFML.length` is the correct thing to check.

For future reference, `exception in thread main java.lang.arrayindexoutofboundsexception: 2` means that you tried to access index `2` of an array that had less than 3 elements (which occurred when you did `nameFML[2]`).

Comment: disagree with this.. user an enter "John David Lee". Then it should have 3 values in the array.. If the user enters "David Lee" then your case holds true

Comment: @G V, I'm not sure what we disagree about. I agree that the original code works with a three part name, but I thought the question was how to make it also work for two part names like John Doe, which my answer addresses.

Comment: @Darby, You made sure that nameFML[2] is only used in places where you know that nameFML.length>2?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Darby: The only place that you can have nameFML[2] is inside the innermost else statement (the one that is reached if the name has three parts). Otherwise, you could be trying to access the third part of a name that only has 2 parts.

Comment: I did have 
 if (nameFML[2]==null)
      {
        System.out.println("Your initials are: " + firstInitial + middleInitial); but I changed it to  if (nameFML.length== 2) and am still getting the same array issue.

Comment: Please post the exact line of code of code where the error is occurring. Is it String lastInitial=nameFML[2]…?

Comment: I believe it's this "if (nameFML.length== 2)" because String lastInitial=nameFML[2] seems to work when you type in 3 names.

Comment: String lastInitial=nameFML[2] works fine with 3 names, but causes an Array out of bounds exception with 2 names because you are trying to read the third element of an array with only two elements in it. Move that line inside the else statement.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping me figure it out. It's much appreciated.

Comment: @Darby: If this answer helped you, please accept it (click the green checkbox). Thanks, and I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

The task is to find the initials. To do that, you don't necessarily need to know the names or even what each initial is.

You can find the initials in just one line of code:

```
String initials = input.replaceAll("(?<\\b\\w)\\w*\\s*", "");
```

This replaces all but the first letters of each word and any trailing spaces with a blank (effe timely deleting them).

The good thing about this code is it will work for any number of names, including just one name or even no names (ie blank input) correctly and importantly without error.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if-else above, use a for loop

```
String firstInitial = "";
String middleInitial = "";
String lastInitial = "";
String[] nameFML = inputName.split(" ");
for(int i=o; i<nameFML.length; i++)
{
if(i==0)
 firstInitial = nameFML[0].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
else if(i=1)
 middleInitial = nameFML[1].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
else if(i=2)
 lastInitial = nameFML[2].substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
}


System.out.println("Your initials are: " + firstInitial + middleInitial + lastInitial);
```